# Android onClickListner on AlertDialog not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a popup that has a custom view composed out of a scroll view, a text view and two buttons at the end of the text. The user has to scroll down and after that press the Yes button ( to accept the terms and conditions, this is the scope ).

On the onCreateView of that fragment I have:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.terms, container, false);
    Button yes_btn = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    builder.setView(customView);
    final AlertDialog termsdialog = builder.create();
    yes_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("adsa", "asdada");
            termsdialog.dismiss();
        }   
    });
    builder.show();
    return rootView;
```

I cannot understand why the onClick method is not called. My goal is to close the pop-up once the user selects Yes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are showing `builder.show();` instead of `termsdialog.show();` and dismissing `termsdialog`.

Just replace line

```
builder.show();
```

by

```
termsdialog.show();
```

It'll solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply! I modified the code ( you were right.. i missed that typo ) but is the same. I first missed that line because I don't even see the Log.d message on the console, I believe the function is not called at all.